# Programmatically get TFS blame (annotation) data

Tags: c#, tfs, annotate, blame

I'm trying to implement a plugin for Team Foundation Server 2010 that will create reports about users in a team project. Conceptually, all I need in order to properly implement this plugin is access to the same data that you get when you use the "Annotate" feature in Visual Studio: *I need to be able to tell who was the last person to author a given line of code.*

I've scoured the Internet for documentation or code samples, but all that I can find are either suggestions such as [using the TFS command-line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74526/tfs-annotate-blame-summary-report-for-a-project) or seemingly incomplete [code samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531408/get-history-of-file-changes-from-tfs-to-implement-custom-blame-behaviour-of-ex).

I don't mind doing a lot of heavy lifting in the client code, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to get useful authorship data about the *contents* of the code in a [Changeset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.aspx), nor from the [merge details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff735782.aspx) return.

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile I found a working solution that executes [Team Foundation Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) process and parses its output:

```
private readonly Regex m_Regex = new Regex(@"^(?<changeset>\d+)(?<codeLine>.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);

public List<Changeset> GetAnnotations(string filepath, string codeText)
    {
        var versionControlServer = CreateVersionControlServer();

        return m_Regex.Matches(ExecutePowerTools(filepath))
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Where(m => m.Groups["codeLine"].Value.Contains(codeText))
            .Select(v => versionControlServer.GetChangeset(int.Parse(v.Groups["changeset"].Value), false, false))
            .ToList();
    }

    private static VersionControlServer CreateVersionControlServer()
    {
        var projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(@"TFS URL"));
        var versionControlServer = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        return versionControlServer;
    }

    private static string ExecutePowerTools(string filepath)
    {
        using (var process = Process.Start(TfptLocation, string.Format("annotate /noprompt {0}", filepath)))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
            return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just implemented this and it doesn't tell you the owner of each line, only the changeset and code...

Comment: @im1dermike, you are right. It was good enough for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar requirement to get details of particular attribute in a file e.g. who added, when, related work items etc.; Following GitHub project is having implementation to get required details and required minimal changes to work-

[SonarQube SCM TFVC plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-tfvc)

It requires analysis to be executed from Windows machines with the Team Foundation Server Object Model installed (download for TFS 2013).